# Recommendation on Project + Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ms-project

I'm posting as a guest so I am new to the site.

I've been tasked with looking for a new project management tool. We are in marketing and communications, so it's normal for a designer to have 10+ projects in their queue.

Just curious as a designer, can I quickly see that tasks I've been assign and update quickly?

Thanks!

Jeremy

Comment: This is could result in many possible answers, please refine your question so it is specific and not opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

As an ordinary engineer and software developer on the side, I've just been tasked with delivering something very similar for our engineering consultancy.  We use SharePoint to monitor everything from bids to tender documents and jobs.  It works well for us in this regard, but it depends on your exact requirements. Tasks lists and Approval Workflows are pretty handy for keeping a track of what's going on, for example, but as I said, it depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks! So do you guys use Microsoft Project as well or solely sharepoint? I was told they tried SharePoint in the past and was unable to track specific times.

Comment: Just SharePoint as opposed to SharePoint plus Project.  With Tasks lists you have some quite useful Project-like views (such as Gantt charts) which you can build automatically with a SharePoint Workflow.